# Filtering a set of data based on indices in line

Tags: python, mysql, sql, filter

I have a python script that pulls data from an external servers SQL database and sum's the values based on transaction numbers. I've gotten some assistance in cleaning up the result sets - which have been a huge help, but now I've hit another problem.

My original query:

```
SELECT th.trans_ref_no, th.doc_no, th.folio_yr, th.folio_mo, th.transaction_date, tc.prod_id, tc.gr_gals FROM TransHeader th, TransComponents tc WHERE th.term_id="%s" and th.source="L" and th.folio_yr="%s" and th.folio_mo="%s" and (tc.prod_id="TEXLED" or tc.prod_id="103349" or tc.prod_id="103360" or tc.prod_id="103370" or tc.prod_id="113107" or tc.prod_id="113093")and th.trans_ref_no=tc.trans_ref_no;
```

Returns a set of data that I've copied a snippet here:

```
"0520227370","0001063257","2014","01","140101","113107","000002000"
"0520227370","0001063257","2014","01","140101","TEXLED","000002550"
"0520227378","0001063265","2014","01","140101","113107","000001980"
"0520227378","0001063265","2014","01","140101","TEXLED","000002521"
"0520227380","0001063267","2014","01","140101","113107","000001500"
"0520227380","0001063267","2014","01","140101","TEXLED","000001911"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000003501"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","TEXLED","000004463"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000004000"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","TEXLED","000005103"
"0520227385","0001063272","2014","01","140101","113107","000007500"
"0520227385","0001063272","2014","01","140101","TEXLED","000009565"
"0520227388","0001063275","2014","01","140101","113107","000002000"
"0520227388","0001063275","2014","01","140101","TEXLED","000002553"
```

The updated query runs this twice and JOINS the trans_ref_no, which is the first position in the result set, so the first 6 lines get condensed into three, and the last four lines get condensed into two. The problem I'm having is getting transaction number 0520227384 to get condensed to two lines.

```
SELECT t1.trans_ref_no, t1.doc_no, t1.folio_yr, t1.folio_mo, t1.transaction_date, t1.prod_id, t1.gr_gals, t2.prod_id, t2.gr_gals FROM (SELECT th.trans_ref_no, th.doc_no, th.folio_yr, th.folio_mo, th.transaction_date, tc.prod_id, tc.gr_gals FROM Tms6Data.TransHeader th, Tms6Data.TransComponents tc WHERE th.term_id="00000MA" and th.source="L" and th.folio_yr="2014" and th.folio_mo="01" and (tc.prod_id="103349" or tc.prod_id="103360" or tc.prod_id="103370" or tc.prod_id="113107" or tc.prod_id="113093") and th.trans_ref_no=tc.trans_ref_no) t1 JOIN (SELECT th.trans_ref_no, th.doc_no, th.folio_yr, th.folio_mo, th.transaction_date, tc.prod_id, tc.gr_gals FROM Tms6Data.TransHeader th, Tms6Data.TransComponents tc WHERE th.term_id="00000MA" and th.source="L" and th.folio_yr="2014" and th.folio_mo="01" and tc.prod_id="TEXLED" and th.trans_ref_no=tc.trans_ref_no) t2 ON t1.trans_ref_no = t2.trans_ref_no;
```

Here is what the new query returns for transaction number 0520227384:

```
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000003501","TEXLED","000004463"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000003501","TEXLED","000005103"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000004000","TEXLED","000004463"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000004000","TEXLED","000005103"
```

What I need to get out of this is a set of condensed lines where, in this group, the seconds and third need to be removed:

```
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000003501","TEXLED","000004463"
"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000004000","TEXLED","000005103"
```

How can I go about filtering these lines from the updated query result set?

Comment: What logic do you have to choose "000004000","TEXLED","000005103"  (line 4) over "000004000","TEXLED","000004463" (line 3), but on the same note choose "000003501","TEXLED","000004463" (line 1) over "000003501","TEXLED","000005103" (line 2)?  One seems to take max and one takes min

Comment: @Twelfth Based on the original query result set. Lines 7-10 are for the same transaction, however, lines 7 and 8 are paired "3501 and 4463" while lines 9 and 10 are paired - "4000 and 5103". You are correct in the statement that it appears to be choosing the max and min, but the resulting data set orders it in that way, so 3501 comes first with a 4463 and 5103, then 4000 with a 4463 and 5103

Answer (score 0):

i think, the answer is:

```
(... your heavy sql ..) group by 7
```

or

```
(... your heavy sql ..) group by t1.gr_gals
```

Comment: Not quite sure if that will do it (mysql would probably run it instead of returning an error.  Yay MySQL).  t1.gr_gals and t2.gr_gals are both different, not just t1.gr_gals.

Comment: @Twelfth The main idea is to use group or window function. I'm not sure how it shall be implemented in mysql. I hope my and will help you.

Comment: @SethKoberg That query shall filter rows by value like `"000003501"` (I may mistype exact row). How your result looks like?

Comment: trying this, the query removes three out of the four transactions in the result set instead of removing only 2. Could it be expanded to something along the lines of `group by 7 where t1.trans_ref_no = t2.trans_ref_no`?

Comment: @akaRem On further inspection, your suggestion didn't remove three, of the results for transaction `0520227384` but it created two with different values in column 7 `000003501' and `000004000`, and the same value in column 9. `"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000003501","TEXLED","000004463"` is the first instance for this transaction number and `"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000004000","TEXLED","000004463"` is the second instance.

Comment: @SethKoberg Is that what you want? Or not? If not, explain, what you want to get more clearly, please.

Comment: @akaRem - Looking at the original data set, lines 7-8 need to be joined to create `"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000003501","TEXLED","000004463"` and lines 9 and 10 need to be joined to create `"0520227384","0001063271","2014","01","140101","113107","000004000","TEXLED","000005103"`